# How to create a directory inside TOMCAT using Java?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, mkdir, create-directory

I'm having troubles trying to create a directory inside my servlet application for saving an audio file. When I try to create it in the root directory: (C:/something) I have no trouble, but when I try to do it inside tomcat path I can't. Does any one know why? 
This is my code (I have to pass the target path by post, but I'm trying first with a path previous set).

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>");
    //nombreFichero = request.getParameter("nombreArchivo");
    //Ruta = request.getParameter("Destino");
    String destino = request.getParameter("Destino");
    String ruta2 = request.getContextPath();
    ruta2 += "/InformesAudio/";
    out.println("<P>Ruta para guardar: <B>" + destino + "</B></P>");
    out.println("<P>Ruta armada: <B>" + ruta2 + "</B></P>");

    File crearCarpeta = new File(destino);
    if(!crearCarpeta.exists())
    {
        crearCarpeta.mkdir();
        out.println("<P>La ruta de getContextPath modificada es: </P><P>" + destino + "</P>"
                    + "<P>CARPETA CREADA EXITOSAMENTE</P>");
    }
```

Thanks for your help buddies!! Have a nice day!! ;)

Comment: @JordiLaforge Ain't not Exceptions making directories :(

Comment: I vaguely recall that tomcat (for security) restricts certain file-system operations in/under the webapp directory... can/should you just move your filestore out of there, to say C:\InformesAudio\?

Comment: @Carol, Have you checked the tomcat logs for errors?

Comment: @corlettk I can't because Im working with an online software, and I have to be able to reproduce it from Internet, so I think it should be inside Tomcat server.

Comment: @corlettk I've checked it but ain't not error. Do you know if creating my directory I have to use "/" or "\\"? I'm asking this coz when I get the context with `request.getContextPath()` I get "/HIS" and I want to create it inside this folder like: "/HIS/InformesAudio/" 
This is making me nuts :( Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: @Carol: You can allways use / as the path seperator character throughout the Java world, as far as I know... I suppose because Java hails from Unix... that and \\ is a kludge.

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

`

```
    public static String WEBAPP_ROOT;
    /**
    *       Initialize the servlet and set up some static variables :<br>
    */
    public void init() {
            WEBAPP_ROOT = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    }`
```

Then you

Comment: Then you what? But I'm glad you found it... and there's no problem actually creating the directory tree, yeah? So you're good to go ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Take the application root and then concatnate destination location. Also try using mkdirs() instead of mkdir(). It will create the parent directories if not present

```
File parent_dirs = new File(applicationRoot + destinationLoc);
if(!parent_dirs.exists()){
  parent_dirs.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work :( I have try this (with "\\" and "/") but I cant. Remember I have to create it inside tomcat directory tree, and I don't know if I can.

`String dir = request.getContextPath();
File TargetRoot = new File(dir + "\\InformesAudio\\");
        if(!TargetRoot.exists())
        {
            TargetRoot.mkdir();
            out.println("<P>La ruta de getContextPath modificada es: </P><P>" + TargetRoot.getPath() + "</P>"
                        + "<P>CARPETA CREADA EXITOSAMENTE</P>"
                    + "<P>El Path Absoluto es: " + TargetRoot.getAbsolutePath() + "</P>");
        }`